# Mobile Safari not accepting setTimeout function binding to this

Tags: javascript, mobile-safari, bind, settimeout

I have a javascript object (that is instantiated several times) that contains `setTimeout` functions. The function is similar to this:

```
setTimeout(function() {
    this.function();
}.bind(this), this.interval);
```

This works fine on all browsers except for Mobile Safari. During my tests on what happened, the error is the result of adding `.bind(this)` to the end of the function declaration in the `setTimeout`. Although it works when I remove the `.bind(this)` in Safari, it stops working on other browsers... Does anyone how I could fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apparently [no versions of mobile Safari support function.bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind#Browser_compatibility).  MDN does provide a [polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind#Compatibility) for it though.